# Is there a build in function in Python to get the size of a list like C++?

Tags: python

When a list has only 1 dimension, `len()` could be used to get the size of it, is there a function to get the size of a nested list?

for example, `test_list = [[1], [2], [3]]`, `len(test_list)` return 3, how to get `(3, 1)` ?

Comment: Why should the result be `(3, 1)`? The sublists can all be different lengths, and can be nested to any depth. They can even be recursive.

Comment: You could use `numpy`: `np.array([[1], [2], [3]]).shape == (3, 1)`. If the inner lists don't have a consistent length, this will create an array of objects, but if they're consistent you'll get a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: `list(map(len, values))` => `[1, 1, 1]`

Comment: @PM 2Ring, eh, I assumed the sublists are in same length, but not realized to figure it out, it is my bad, Thank you for your kind reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because amount of elements of your array is indeed 3, if you'd like to check depths of its contents you could do (note that depth of second dimension will be maximum length of its contents)

```
test_list = [[1], [2], [3]]

print((len(test_list), max(len(i) for i in test_list))) # -> (3, 1)
```

Or using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

test_list = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
print(test_list.shape) # -> (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a numpy array instead of list then you can get the shape which will be (3, 1).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

print(a.shape)
```